# Flatten JaxB objects

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I have a very complex xml structure like so

```
<root>
 <a>
   <b>
      <c>testc</c> 
      <e>teste</e>
   <b>
   <d>testd</d>
 </a>
...
</root>
```

with more then 100 nodes. The nodes are simple and don't have attributes. I'm using xjc (JaxB binding compiler) to generate POJO objects from the xsd file. But because the xsd has a tree structure xjc is generating 100 objects.

Can I flatten the output generated by xjc and have a single object with all the properties like so:

```
class Root {
 private String c;
 private String e;
 private String d;
 ...
}
```

instead of 100 objects?

Ideally I would be interested in both marshalling and unmarshalling using this concept!

Comment: Can you add the XSD please?

Answer (score 0):

There's [some documentation on cyclic references](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html), but I can't tell from your XML if that's the problem.

You could use your flat `Root` approach, but you'd lose the ability to reproduce the original structure by ignoring the container tags. 
You can configure much, and write your own fragment (de)serializers even, but at a certain point it gets too complex when trying to fit an XML tree into a single-noded JAXB POJO.

As far as I can tell you are only interested in being able to edit the values of single-lettered tags with Text content. Perhaps you can simplify your interface by using XSLT to transform the source document into a document that maps 1-to-1 to your POJO, but you'd also have to write the reverse XSLT.

An alternative approach is to simply load the XML into a generic DOM, and use XPath (like `//a/text()`) to access the editable nodes. You're probably using getters and setters for the properties, already, so you can have them call a `private getText( String tagName )` and a `private setText( String tagName, String value)` to read and modify the DOM directly. These functions would simply use [Document.getElementsByTagName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) and [Node.(get|set)TextContent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29).

Comment: thank you for your input. I don't have a cyclic problem. I just have to many fields and I'm trying to automate as much as possible. Using DOM is not a solution as I'm working with large documents. Also XSLT would make me write the mappings by hand and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: If DOM is too large than JAXB will be too - the entire tree will be in memory, just with a different model. If memory is a concern, take a look at [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/). Otherwise, you're going to have to write some code to deal with the complexity of the model - it is a tree structure, not a flat list. Show the XSD; If there's redundancy in the generated code and not in the XSD, you can probably reduce that by adding some annotations.